# Set Network Location windows appeared, ipConfig showed an active adapter/address I don't recognize

Tags: windows, networking

This is really a mystery I'm looking for help investigating.  I don't know if this is legit somehow or if I've been hacked in a weird way...  So here is everything I know:

I leave my computer on 24x7 as it is a server of sorts as well.

Yesterday morning I saw the "Set Network Location" screen up, asking if "Network 8" should be considered a home, work, or public network.  This does NOT happen routinely.  I ran IPConfig and sure enough, there was a network with address 172.20.10.10, gateway of 172.20.10.1.  I had to go to work, and did not have time to look further.

When I returned, the window is still up, but IPConfig does NOT show the network is operating.

In the registry I found:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Adapters{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} (I've removed the GUID)

with IpConfig value pointing to the next entry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} (same GUID as above)

Which has the following values:

```
"UseZeroBroadcast"=dword:00000000
"EnableDeadGWDetect"=dword:00000001
"EnableDHCP"=dword:00000001
"NameServer"=""
"Domain"=""
"RegistrationEnabled"=dword:00000001
"RegisterAdapterName"=dword:00000000
"DhcpIPAddress"="172.20.10.10"
"DhcpSubnetMask"="255.255.255.240"
"DhcpServer"="172.20.10.1"
"Lease"=dword:00014e20
"LeaseObtainedTime"=dword:58401e47
"T1"=dword:5840c557
"T2"=dword:584142a3
"LeaseTerminatesTime"=dword:58416c67
"AddressType"=dword:00000000
"IsServerNapAware"=dword:00000000
"DhcpConnForceBroadcastFlag"=dword:00000000
"DhcpInterfaceOptions"=hex:06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,\
  6c,41,58,ac,14,0a,01,03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,6c,\
  41,58,ac,14,0a,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,6c,41,\
  58,ff,ff,ff,f0,36,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,6c,41,58,\
  ac,14,0a,01,35,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,6c,41,58,05,\
  00,00,00,33,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,67,6c,41,58,00,01,\
  4e,20,fc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,5d,68,40,58
"DhcpGatewayHardware"=hex:ac,14,0a,01,06,00,00,00,e2,5f,45,8c,c4,64
"DhcpGatewayHardwareCount"=dword:00000001
"DhcpNameServer"="172.20.10.1"
"DhcpDefaultGateway"=hex(7):31,00,37,00,32,00,2e,00,32,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,30,\
  00,2e,00,31,00,00,00,00,00
"DhcpSubnetMaskOpt"=hex(7):32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,\
  00,35,00,35,00,2e,00,32,00,34,00,30,00,00,00,00,00
```

This is indeed the IP address I saw yesterday. So, here is my question...
This sure looks like a software/VPN network connection, but not one I recognize.  I do use OpenVPN, and I do have a TUN adapter being used by that.  But that connection was already up as well...

I tried to find out more with this command, but it shows only connected interfaces...:

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int show int

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 2
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Local Area Connection 3
```

I have now searched for ways to display NIC information for all NICs installed and came across this command, which I think has answered my question (I'm investigating as I write..)  The command (at command prompt) is "wmic nic get" which returns a large table of information about each adapter defined in text form.  I piped it to a text file, then use a fixed space font to view it.  Or, better still, you can limit the columns returned if you know which ones you want, as follows:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic nic get Caption, NetConnectionID
Caption                                                   NetConnectionID               
[00000000] WAN Miniport (SSTP)                                                          
[00000001] WAN Miniport (IKEv2)                                                         
[00000002] WAN Miniport (L2TP)                                                          
[00000003] WAN Miniport (PPTP)                                                          
[00000004] WAN Miniport (PPPOE)                                                         
[00000005] WAN Miniport (IPv6)                                                          
[00000006] WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)                                               
[00000007] Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller                                           
[00000008] WAN Miniport (IP)                                                            
[00000009] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                                                     
[00000010] RAS Async Adapter                                                            
[00000011] Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter                                           
[00000012] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                                                     
[00000013] VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport                                
[00000014] VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport                                
[00000015] TAP-Windows Adapter V9                         Local Area Connection 2       
[00000016] VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport                                
[00000017] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                                                     
[00000018] Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller             Local Area Connection 3       
[00000019] VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter          VirtualBox Host-Only Network  
[00000020] Apple Mobile Device Ethernet                                                 
[00000021] Microsoft 6to4 Adapter                                                       
[00000022] VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport                                
[00000023] Microsoft ISATAP Adapter                                                     
[00000024] Apple Mobile Device Ethernet                                                 
[00000025] VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver Miniport
```

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Indeed.  I mistakenly thought I had to wait, but I only have to wait to accept the answer.  So I've edited the question, moving the answer out of the question to the answer below.

Comment: Great. Perfect! ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I reviewed all these NICs to see if I thought they belong.  There are those for VirtualBox, and OpenVPN.  I discovered the "Apple Mobile Device Ethernet" (two of them) that I did not install myself, but were probably put there by iTunes (I have an iPhone).  Suddenly I remembered that my phone was indeed plugged in that morning.  I had plugged it in to charge and walked away, so I did not see that this window opened shortly after plugging the phone in...  So I plugged it in again, and now I've discovered I had left the "personal hotspot" feature on in my phone settings.  And sure enough, a new adapter came up.  IPConfig confirmed it has the same address/subnet as I saw the other day as well.

So yesterday was the first time I plugged my phone into this computer with the hotspot feature turned on... That explains the pop up window!  And the strange adapter.